# How to distinguish flash disk based on disk name on Redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

I'm writing a system which can distinguish flash disk one from another based on the name of the disk. The input is the name of the disk(volume label), the output is the path of disk in OS view, for instance, `F:/` on windows or `/Media/somebody/volome_label` on linux.

On windows, I can get the map between volume label and drive letter based on  Microsoft library like [GetLogicalDrives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetVolumeInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993(v=vs.85).aspx).

But on Redhat, all I can get is `sdb1`, `sdb2`... under `dev` folder when I plug a disk into the machine. Is there any way for me to know which device it is by disk name. For instance, the input is `GearonDisk` and the output is `sdb2`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14165/list-partition-labels-from-the-command-line?

Comment: Which mapping are you looking for?  Your example `/media/somebody...` is a mounted volume so examining the mount table will provide some of the answer.  Or are you trying to trace how [`udev'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) connects raw device to volume?

Comment: @wallyk Yes, what I want to know is how 'udev`, especially the flash disk inserted by user, connects raw device to volume. If I know which device it is, I can mount it to any path I want.

Comment: @melpomene, thanks for this link, let me try solutions listed.

Comment: @melphmene, the command `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label` can do the trick, thanks for your help